# Find value in json if certain or all words matches to key of json

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an json:

```
const apple ={"YABADABADU":"scoobydoo","somebody stop me":"mask","details":"somedetails","alpha":"romero"}
```

but sometimes it could be:

```
const apple = {"yabada":"scoobydoo", "somebody me" : "mask","details":"somedetails","alpha":"romero"}
```

It's just sample data based on certain extraction that will always contain, all or either part as, yabadabadu can be yabada , yaba , yabadabadu, YABADABADU and somebody stop me can be somebody, some, body.

For this I tried as

```
console.log(apple.includes('yaba').tolowercase())
```

But it's giving me error.

I just want to pass data to some other variable, let's say,

```
const banana = apple.yaba 
const mango = apple.some
```

and on

```
 console.log(banana) -> should give o/p "scoobydoo"
 console.log(mango) -> should give o/p "mask"
```

P.S. I want to set value for yaba and some , not for details and alpha

What could be the solution for this. If anyone need any further information , please  let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code sandbox that builds on Ran's answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hellman-o13nc?file=/src/index.js

The `results` is an array of keys you can use to access the data inside of `apple`

Comment: Thank you so much...this is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would add an array which holds the possible prefixes.

Now, you can iterate through the key of the apple object and check if it contains one of the possible prefixes..

```js
const apple ={"YABADABADU":"scoobydoo","somebody stop me":"mask"};

const possiblePrefix = ["yaba", "some", "body"]; //you can add here the rest of the posiible prefixes..

for (var key in apple){
   if (possiblePrefix.some(x => key.toLowerCase().includes(x))){
        console.log(apple[key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the value, such that console.log(apple.yaba) , should give me the value, scoobydoo, or console.log(apple.some) , should give mask.

Comment: Also, I don't want the loop as I just want to pass data to some other variable, let's say,

const banana = apple.yaba 
and on console.log(banana) -> should give scoobydoo

Comment: If yoy want the value. Just reference it like this: apple[key]

Comment: Thank you for your time. Bu could you please have a look at the edited question as I might have not been clear before. I want to set value to some let's say variable

Comment: I changed the snippet to print the value. Is that better?